# Google sheet trend chart help

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

Is there a way to display this years data like it is in this chart but have a cut off so the line doesn't drop to 0?

Please see attached image

Many thanks

[image: Chart]

Answer (score 0):

Select your chart. Go to the **Customize** menu. Scroll down to the **Vertical Axis**. Then, set your minimum value. Make sure your 'Allow bounds to hide data' is ticked on.